# geometry nodes : limit to X edges connecting each vertex

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges

I have this mesh generated through Geometry Nodes.

[image]

Is there a way to delete edges, **based on a maximum number of edges connecting each vertex ?** I want to achieve something similar to the Plexus plugin for After Effects, which has (among others) this option.

[image]

In my case, this might filter edges to get something like this:

[image]

I’ve seen the `Vertex Neightbours` node, which can output how many edges a vertex has, but once I know that, I don’t know how I can remove some n-1 edges.

Thanks !

Comment: *"I would like to keep only one edge maximum connecting each vertex."* ...and what is the criterion according to which the correct edge is selected, should several edges be connected to one point?

Comment: For now, I would like to find a way to limit to X edges conneting a vertex (like you can on the Plexus plugin for After Effects). No specific rule. Later, i’ll try to filter some of the edges depending on their angle…

Comment: In principle, you could achieve this with the help of the node `Vertex Neighbors` or `Edge Angle`. However, it is still not clear to me what the final result should look like.

Comment: Thanks @quellenform, question edited.  I’ve already checked Vertex Neightbors - which is helpful but I don’t see how to remove the « extra edges » after that.

Comment: OK, I see, but what is still not clear: What rule defines which are the "extra edges"? For example, in the center of the image there is a point connected with nine edges. Which of them is the "extra edge"?

Comment: I don't know how to "rule" that.   The one to keep might be the first one in the spreadsheet list, or a random one.